# MYSQL Query issue with group of rows

Tags: mysql, null, distinct

I am trying to obtain the following results from my MySQL database:

1) I have a table with the following 3 columns ( `time_in`, `time_out`, `receipt_number`)

2) Consider in this table I have the following rows inserted:

```
+--------------------+---------------------+----------------+
|     time_in        |     time_out        | receipt_number |
+--------------------+---------------------+----------------+
|2016-12-24 13:33:33 | 2016-12-24 13:52:52 |  1             |
|2016-12-24 13:44:44 | 2016-12-24 13:55:55 |  1             |
|2016-12-24 13:33:33 | 2016-12-24 13:55:55 |  2             |
|2016-12-24 13:35:35 | NULL                |  2             |
+--------------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

3) I need to obtain out of these rows all the receipts (group by) which have `NOT NULL` values in all their rows which contain the same receipt_number in "`time_out`" column which means I need to extract only receipt number 2.

```
SELECT DISTINCT receipt_number FROM orders 
WHERE time_in >= CURDATE() AND time_in < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
(time_out IS NOT NULL OR time_out != "")
ORDER BY time_in ASC
```

However the above query returns both receipt_numbers as "receipt_number 2" contains one NON NUll value

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: (time_out IS NOT NULL **OR** time_out != "") -> (time_out IS NOT NULL **AND** time_out != "")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM receipt_number t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT receipt_number
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY receipt_number
    HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN time_out IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
) t2
    ON t1.receipt_number = t2.receipt_number
```

The subquery aliased as `t2` finds receipt numbers having all records with non `NULL` time out values.  This is then used to restrict the `orders` table to the records you want to see.

Comment: brother thank you for the answer. it is working like a charm. with this i will able to obtain all the orders which are completed. i will also try the opposite in case i need to retrieve the non completed receipts. Thank you. Have a wonderful new year

Comment: i did not understand your question? if you are asking me if the query on top worked then yes